# scoring with not analyzed field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't need score and want to find exact match with term string. If i set field "name" as not analyzed field and send queries like below. They will compute score? if so, how could I not to compute score for better performance?

query 1

```
"query" : {
  "must" : {
    "term" : {
      "name" : "Jone Park"
    }
  }
}
```

query 2

```
"query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "term" : {
        "name" : "Tic tok"
      }
    }, {
      "term" : {
        "name" : "Jon Park"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the 2nd example in OP  needs to be a  `should` and not must . how can name be "jon Park" & "Tic Toc"

Comment: Sorry, it was short version of my origin query, but it's not matter should or must. My question was 'It will compute score or not'

Comment: specify them as filters to prevent scores from being computed as shown below